# Alternate page with proper canonical tag and duplicate URL part errors in Google search console report

Tags: vue.js, seo, markdown, nuxt.js, canonical-link

I have a static blog site created with Nuxt and hosted on Netlify. For content, I am using markdown files and the new [Content module](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/creating-blog-with-nuxt-content) in Nuxt. I used Nuxt and static content, along with [vue-meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/) for SEO purposes, but after a couple months, my coverage report shows multiple errors, and I can't get any pages returned in Google, even when searching on the site name or a specific string of text used on the site.

Here's my setup:

1. My markdown content is stored in `/content/posts`
2. In my `blog/index.vue` file, this is what I have for my meta tags and data fetching:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Posts',
  head() {
    return {
      title: 'Blog Posts',
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: 'Example Site blog index'
        },
        {
          hid: 'link',
          name: 'link',
          content: 'https://example.com/blog'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const posts = await $content('posts', params.slug)
      .only(['title', 'description', 'publishDate', 'slug'])
      .sortBy('publishDate', 'desc')
      .fetch()

    return {
      posts
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

3. In my `/blog/_slug/index.vue` page, I'm doing almost the same thing.

```
export default {
  name: 'Post',
  computed: {
    pageConfig() {
      return {
        identifier: this.post.slug
      }
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.post.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: this.post.description
        },
        {
          property: "og:site_name",
          hid: "og:site_name",
          vmid: "og:site_name",
          content: "My Site Name"
        },
        {
          property: "og:title",
          hid: "og-title",
          vmid: "og-title",
          content: this.post.title
        },
        {
          property: "og:description",
          hid: "og-description",
          vmid: "og-description",
          content: this.post.description
        },
        {
          property: "og:type",
          hid: "og-type",
          vmid: "og-type",
          content: "article"
        },
        {
          property: "og:url",
          hid: "og-url",
          vmid: "og-url",
          content: 'https://example.com/blog/' + this.post.slug
        },
        {
          hid: "link",
          name: "link",
          content: 'https://example.com/blog/' + this.post.slug
        },
      ],
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'canonical',
          href: 'https://example.com/blog/' + this.post.slug
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const post = await $content('posts', params.slug).fetch()

    return  {
      post
    }
  },
}
```

4. I'm using this to generate my sitemap in `nuxt.config.js`

```
  sitemap: {
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    hostname: process.env.BASE_URL,
    gzip: true,
    routes: async () => {
      let routes = []
      const { $content } = require('@nuxt/content')
      let posts = await $content('posts').fetch()
      for (const post of posts) {
        routes.push(`blog/${post.slug}`)
      }
      return routes
    },
  }
```

and this generates a sitemap at `/sitemap.xml` with the following structure

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/blog/blog-post-1</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/blog/blog-post-2</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/blog/blog-post-3</loc>
</url>


</urlset>
```

5. I submitted my sitemap to Google.

When I look at my Coverage report in Google Search Console, I have two main problems:

1. A large number of posts listed under `Not Found (404)` with a URL of `https://example.com/blog/blog/my-blog-post` (two `/blog`s in the URL). I've noticed this happens sometimes when I click on a post right after deploying to Netlify. I've looked around the code, and I can't find where I might be adding an extra `/blog` in the URL.
2. An equally large number under `Alternate page with proper canonical tag`. Before I put the canonical tag in my `/_slug/index/vue` header, I got errors about missing a canonical tag, and now that I put that in, I get this error instead.

What do I need to do to fix these errors and get my content correctly indexed?

Comment: I have the same problem. Google claims to be able to handle SPA indexing and the page is seen correctly in Google Search consoles "live test". Nevertheless the indexing is heavily broken despite of a correct sitemap and injected canonical urls. 

Did you find a way to solve this problem?